# "Memory Is Not Detected" on ASRock Z87 OC Formula/ac

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building, ddr3

I have a "ASRock Z87 OC Forumla/ac" motherboard that will not recognize my memory.   Here are the memory specs that the board supports:

- 4x240 pin
- DDR3 3000+(OC)/2933(OC)/2800(OC)/2400(OC)/2133(OC)/1866(OC)/1600/1333/1066

The RAM that we're trying is "G.SKILL F3-2400C10D-16GTX" which are 2 8 GB sticks and it's specs are:

- Type - 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM
- Speed - DDR3 2400 (PC3 19200)
- Voltage - 1.65V

The processor being used is an Intel Core i7-4790K 4.0GHz quad-core processor.

The issue that I'm having is when attempting to power on the board, the on-board LCD tells me that the "Memory is not detected". It is plugged in the black slots (1st and 3rd) as it is the only ports it would fit into. I thought maybe it would need to be overclocked to work (please excuse my ignorance, it's my first build for a friend) but I cannot get to the BIOS.

I'm not sure if will help but the other parts are listed below, I apologize if I left out any details needed.

- CPU Cooler - Corsair H100i 77.0 CFM Liquid CPU Cooler
- Video Card - Sapphire Radeon R9 290X 8GB Vapor-X Video Card
- Case - Cooler Master HAF A ATX Full Tower Case
- Power Supply - Corsair Professional 1050W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-Modular ATX Power Supply
- Optical Drive - Asus DRW-24B1ST/BLK/B/AS DVD/CD Writer
- Primary Drive - WD Black<sup>2</sup> Dual Drive 2.5" 120 GB SSD + 1 TB HDD Kit WD1001X06XDTL
- Secondary Drive - Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RMP Internal Hard Drive

Comment: Make sure BIOS has latest update. Check the stick are working fine individually.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct type of memory? 1.65V memory doesn't seem right to me. You should be using 1.35V or 1.5V memory.

Comment: @vembutech can I update the BIOS if I cannot get the computer to turn on even to the BIOS screen?

Comment: @DragonLord I can't find those specs anywhere for the board, if the board doesn't take 1.65 then I have to replace with 1.35 or 1.5?

Comment: @JackVaughn - **Yes;** You should update the firmware if you have that capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G.Skill "F3-2400C10Q-16GTX" is on the [supported memory list for that board](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z87%20OC%20Formulaac/?cat=Memory).

It's the SAME RAM as what you have (G.SKILL F3-2400C10D-16GTX).  The "Q" just means a Quad-Channel ([4 sticks in one pack](http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-2400c10q-16gtx)) and the "D" just mean "Dual Channel" ([2 sticks in the pack](http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-2400c10d-16gtx)).

One thing to note this that RAM has actually have an SPD voltage rating of 1.5V, but it's been "tested" at 1.65V for over-clocking/over-volting.

So the RAM model you have should work perfectly fine.  You most likely either have faulty RAM, or a faulty motherboard.  Time to start swapping in known-good parts to determine who's the culprit.

Since you've decided to start building computers, you now get to learn a lesson that seem to surprise many people: YOU NEED SPARE PARTS FOR TESTNG. :)

Test the RAM in a known-good motherboard/system, and/or test the motherboard with known-good RAM.  Also, try it once with a known-good power supply as well (since it's an easy test).

If you don't have spares, then you're going to either have to:

1. Guess which part may be broken, start an RMA return, and hope that your hardware supplier will take the untested parts back as faulty.  They may be lenient the first time or two, but they may not be come the second or third time you send a part in that you claim is faulty when it's not.  Wait for replacement part, try new part, repeat until system works.
2. Pack it up and take it to a seasoned professional who has the spares to do the work, and pay them to get it diagnosed and/or working.

Comment: *Why* would a board manufacturer consider 1.65V memory to be OK when it's clearly not compatible with Haswell? Desktop Haswell isn't designed for memory voltages of 1.5V±5%.

Comment: @DragonLord It's the RAM stick manufacturer saying that the memory has been tested to 1.65V, not ASRock. It's DDR3 RAM, so it could be used in, say, a system with a Nehalem CPU, which allows up to 1.65V before releasing magic smoke.

Comment: @ Techie007 - Turns out both the RAM and the motherboard are faulty! I tried putting the RAM in one stick at a time, one booted up and the other did not. Then the board kept cutting off and restarting between 15 seconds to 3 minutes. After talking to ASRock support they told me the board was defective and to send it back to Newegg. Thank you guys very much for your quick responses and all your help! This is much different from simple iPhone/Mac and PC repairs (HDD swap outs). Are faulty parts common for builds like this?